# Event handling in JavaScript/Browser

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I was recently pondering over rendering style of browsers, and decided to try out this simple code:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('button clicked');
});

btn.click();
console.log('after click');
```

```html
  <button id="btn">Button</button>
```

To my surprise, the console printed "button clicked" before "after clicked". I thought the click handler on `btn` will execute asynchronously, but that does not seem to be the case. So a few questions:

1. Aren't click handlers processed via the event loop?
2. If not, then how is this code running synchronously? JS is executed without "interruption", meaning that all callbacks should be run after the current code has finished running (and the click handler *is* a callback).
3. Do all event handlers other than the ones pertaining to AJAX run synchronously?

Comment: `click();` calls the event handler synchronously. An actual user-initiated click is processed via the event loop.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: How does `click()` work internally? It's still bound by JS execution rules, so it should have been processed as async, unless the browser is somehow pausing the currently running script internally and asking the JS engine to process the handler first.

Comment: `click()` takes the idea of "execution without interruption" and applies it to to the event handler(s). It doesn't "pause the currently running script" any more than `console.log` "pauses the currently running script" to write to the log; it *is* the currently running script, and makes the event handler(s) the currently running script as well.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: Can you explain how exactly is the browser making the event handler the "currently running script"? When `click` is called on `btn`, the browser will dispatch a click event, and look for the associated event handler. This process doesn't happen on the main thread. The main thread is executing the JS code and after executing `btn.click()`, it immediately has `console.log('after click')` in queue to be processed. So how exactly is the browser "inserting" the event handler in the main thread before `console.log('after click')`?

Comment: Let's flip this around. How do you know the dispatch process "doesn't happen on the main thread"? [The recommendation says nothing about threads](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dispatching-events). I think you have some ideas that you think are "given" that you may need to reconsider.

Comment: Because all events are processed on a separate thread, which is why you have the event queue. How do you think an ajax call runs at the same time your JS code is running? Or a setTimeout "keeps a counter" while other JS code runs? Browser APIs like Ajax, setTimeout, click events, etc are not "processed" on the main thread. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events). And as far as the ECMA/DOM spec is concerned, it nowhere talks about how to implement the spec. That's upto the browser makers. So referring specs for threading info ain't helpful.